# ag-grid how to change paste range delimiter

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I would like to allow pasting by tab separated data into an ag-grid column rather than a row. Right now, newline separated data will paste into columns and tab separated data will paste into rows. The documentation mentions a "clipboardDeliminator" field of the GridOptions for changing the delimiter for pasting into rows, but that does not seem to apply to columns. Is there any way to have both tab and newline separated data automatically paste into columns?

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you edit the source code. The function you would need to look for is `ClipboardService.prototype.dataToArray` which is taken directly from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1293163/5187323). There are a number of ways that this function could be edited, it mostly depends on how you are expecting the data to be pasted into your table.

You could also suggest an enhancement on their [github page](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues).